# Cannot submit form using Python's Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I wrote the following script to submit a file [here](http://codeforces.com/problemset/submit) .
The login works fine. I'm not able to re-submit to one problem more than once, but it works fine when submitting for the first time.

```
import mechanize
import cookielib

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html2text
import urllib2

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)


br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

# Logging in
br.open('http://codeforces.com/enter')
br.select_form(nr=1)
br.form['handle'] = username
br.form['password'] = password
br.submit()

# Submitting
br.open('http://codeforces.com/problemset/submit')
br.select_form(nr=1)
br.form['submittedProblemCode'] = problemCode
#selecting language
br.form['programTypeId'] = ['42']
br.form.add_file(open("code.cpp"), 'text/plain', "code.cpp")
br.submit()
print br.geturl()
```

For a successful submission, `br.geturl()` prints

`http://codeforces.com/problemset/status`

which is the required page, but for an unsuccessful submission it prints

```
http://codeforces.com/problemset/submit?csrf_token=/insert token/
```